# Density of discrete random vector

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $(X,Y)$ be a discrete random vector with density
$$
f(x,y)=c\frac{2^{x+y}}{x!y!} I_{(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0}(x,y).
$$

I am supposed to compute the value of the constant $c$.

I know that for $f$ to be a density function, it must hold

$$
\sum_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0} f(x,y) = 1.
$$

By using this, I tried:
\begin{align}
1 &= \sum_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0} c\frac{2^{x+y}}{x!y!} \\ 
&= c \sum_{x\in\mathbb{N}_0} \frac{2^x}{x!} \sum_{y\in\mathbb{N}_0} \frac{2^y}{y!} \\
&= c \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!} \\
&= c \cdot (e^2)^2 \\ &= ce^4,
\end{align}

which means that $c=e^{-4}$. Am I correct? I'm not completely sure if the second equality sign holds.

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: You're correct. Is it the step where you get rid of the infinite sums you are unsure about? It is by the Taylor expansion of $e^x$, which exists everywhere and is given by $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Comment: @HowDoIMath No, about turning one infinite sum into two is the step I'm worried about. It's the second equation, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing you concern, you can refer to the following general result. Let $\{a_{m,n}\}$ be a collection of numbers indexed by the natural numbers in both entries (so $m\in\mathbb{N_0}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N_0}$).

If $a_{m,n}\geq 0$ for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N_0}$, then

$$\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{N_0}\times\mathbb{N_0}}a_{m,n} = \sum_{m\in\mathbb{N_0}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}a_{m,n}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N_0}}a_{m,n},$$
with the understanding that the common value can be $+\infty$ in case of divergence. This follows from a more general result called [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions).

In your case, we have that $a_{m,n}=\frac{2^{m+n}}{m!n!}$, which are certainly positive terms. Thus
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{N_0}\times\mathbb{N_0}}\frac{2^{m+n}}{m!n!}&=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N_0}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}\frac{2^{m+n}}{m!n!}\\
&=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N_0}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}\frac{2^m2^n}{m!n!}\\
&=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N_0}}\frac{2^m}{m!}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}\frac{2^n}{n!},\\
\end{align*}$$
where the first equality follows from the result I mentioned above, and where the last equality follows from $\frac{2^m}{m!}$ not depending on $n$.